# How to upload meta data with files using graphql Altair and strapi

Tags: graphql, strapi

I have created this contentType collection called Tests as in the screenshot, i need a mutation query where i can upload meta data such as name and userid which are strings and multipart-files

i tried like this:

```
mutation{
  createTest(input: {data:{name:"hello", userId:"1232"}}) {
    test {
      name
      userId
    }
  }
}
```

but how can i add someFiles attribute to this query to be able to upload multipart files?

[image]